# Download text file or image throw javascript on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying to download a file using a http link.
This is the code:

```
downloadFile: function (fileName, url) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
    link.setAttribute('type', 'application/octet-stream');
    link.target = '_blank';
    link.href = url;

    document.body.appendChild(link);

    link.click();

    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

This works on Chrome and Edge but not on Firefox.
When I tried to download a text file or image, the browser opens a new tab this the file content rendered. I need that the browser open the default download window.

Is it possible?

This is an example of URL that I use: http://localhost:17671/docstmp/528d149e37467a53faeeeb0556901d87/ToDo.txt

I created this jsfiddle to demonstrate: jsfiddle.net/hp7yod85

Comment: Wouldn't a normal download link work?

Comment: What is purpose of including `link.setAttribute('type', 'application/octet-stream'); link.target = '_blank';`?

Comment: Without the target, the file content is opening in the same page as my application.

And the type was a test to try the download

Comment: I can't use a normal link because the server will return the URL dynamic, it isn't a static link

Comment: The `type` attribute does not appear to be necessary. File file should not open, but should display `Save File` dialog. Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate?

Comment: I created this jsfiddle to demonstrate https://jsfiddle.net/hp7yod85/

Answer (score 0):

The requested resource does not have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set, and has `X-Frame-Options` header set to `SAMEORIGIN` to prevent loading into `<iframe>` element.

You can use [`YQL`](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql) to retrieve content, then create a `data URL` of text content at returned results, then create an `<a>` element with `href` set to `data URL`. Returns expected result of opening dialog which prompts to open file within text editor or save file at firefox 47.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <button onclick="downloadFile()">Test</button>
  <script>
  function downloadFile() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q='
              + 'select * from html where '
              + 'url="http://www.ietf.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt"&format=json&callback='
    request.open("GET", url);
    request.onload = function() {
      var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText).query.results.body.content;
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = "data:text/plain," + data;
      a.download = "bcp47.txt";
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    }
    request.send()
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/8JBBhVwIy0Icr2MaQZif?p=preview

Comment: I think that will no solve, because I can also download large files, like a rar with 700mb. Locks like with this solution the user will not see the progress from the default download window

Comment: You can can include `progress` event at `XMLHttpRequest` object to notify user of file download progress. Original Question does not mention downloading 700MB files, or `progress` events?

Comment: Yes, but I will have to implement the cancel event also... And everything are alredy done by the browser

Comment: @LuigiMaestrelli _"but I will have to implement the cancel event also"_ What do you mean by "cancel" event? This is not described at original Question. Original Question describes issue downloading file at firefox; not `progress` or "cancel" events? You can abort the `XMLHttpRequest` if necessary. Not certain what you are referencing at "And everything are alredy done by the browser"? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . All relevant portions of expected result and current issue should be included at original Question, instead of at comments

Comment: @LuigiMaestrelli _"I need that the browser open the default download window."_ appears to be requirement as described at original Question